# Incorrect query filter according to the requirement

Tags: asp.net, oracle, gridview

My requirement wholly depends on the `QUERY`.

I am filtering my gridview on the basis of `three parameters`.

1. `Project_name` (Always required)
2. `Date` (Not always)
3. `Vehicle_No` (Not always)

So, What my requirment is,

> With `project_name` either any one can be used for filtering my gridview.

Currently my debugged query works exactly fine for any two parameters.

Below is my debugged query:-

The above query shows me the exact result for `project_name` and `Date` which I entered.

[![Image 1][1]][1]

But when I add the third parameter say `Vehicle_no` it doesn't show the data for that exact `vehicle_no` it still shows me the same data which I looked for `2` parameters.

[![Image 2][2]][2]

I am using **`ORACLE`** for the database. Kindly help

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but I understand that the condition on `Vehicle_n`o is in `OR` with the condition on `date_in`, while the condition on `date_in` is always satisfied in your records

Comment: @Aleksej: so what should be the exact condition so that, it can match with 2 parameters and also with 3 parameters

Comment: Maybe you need something like project_id=... AND (date_in = ... OR vehicle_n = ...).

Comment: **can you add that in query and show**.?? will check and update you if it works or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to edit your `WHERE` condition this way:

```
WHERE gd.good_type_code(+) = sv.good_type
  AND sv.project_id = '1368'
  AND NVL('26-11-2015',  TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy') ) = TO_CHAR (date_in, 'dd-MM-yyyy')
  AND NVL('0',           vehicle_no                      ) = vehicle_no
  AND sv.delete_flag = 'N'
```

This way it should match 3 parameters exactly, if you use 3, or 2 exactly if you use 2, without giving any value to the third parameter. I'm assuming that `vehicle_no` and `date_in` are always `not null` in your table.

PS: I see you have no join conditions on `xxacl_xxgid_user_mst`; is it ok?

Comment: yes, that's ok. but your logic is not working when I take all the three parameters :((

Comment: Edited to match with 2 or 3 params.

Comment: when I check for matching date, nothing is displayed in the grid.

Comment: I assumed that when you have no filter on a field, the value passed to the query is `NULL`; what values does your grid pass for `date_in` and `vehicle_no` if no values are selected in your dropdown list?

Comment: first I check only for 2 parameters. ie. `project_name` and `date` which shows nothing in the grid, inspite of the data into the database.

Comment: Let's talk on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101584/incorrect-query-filter-according-to-the-requirement)

Comment: you can repost the answer here, so that I can mark it if you want :)

Comment: Having a doubt if it works only for date_in = 26-11-2015